# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a new hard drive and booting from It

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, ssd

I've just bought SSD and installed 12.04 on it. I have 11.10 on my old hard drive. However I can't boot from SSD since grub and everything else is on the hdd.

How do I set Ubuntu to boot from SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did as described in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973947 and it worked. Still need to be checked on updates, but I think it will be ok.

The commands are:

```
sudo install-grub /dev/sdb
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

Hit `ENTER` at each question in dpkg-reconfigure until it lists your hard drives and has asterisks beside them. Add an asterisk to the new harddrive and that will keep your grub configuration up to date. You can then do a `sudo grub-update` to make sure all your available OSes are listed in the boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

- Open your BIOS.
- Go to boot device priority
- Both hard disk should be listed there, set your SSD above old hdd in priority.
- Save and Exit. Now it should boot from your SSD.
- run `sudo update-grub`. This will list your old OS in grub menu if you want so.